# How do I get a subscription key for Microsoft Cognitive Services APIs?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

I'm trying to use the Academic Knowledge Graph / APIs, but haven't found a way to get an API key for it. Initially, I thought the subscription key was one of two "keys" I was given at a certain point, but they didn't work. I'm having trouble finding where those keys are exactly now.

However, I did find a link to the docs: https://dev.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56332331778daf02acc0a50b/operations/565d9001ca73072048922d97. Here it shows a URL to get a key:

[image: Subscription Key, where to get it]

That URL is: https://dev.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/developer. Which takes me to an OAuth sign-in page. When I try to sign in, an error is produced:

[image: Unable to complete request]

Upon close inspection, there is an error message in the URL:

> error=unauthorized_client&error_description=The+client+does+not+exist.+If+you+are+the+application+developer%2c+configure+a+new+application+through+the+application+management+site+at+https://apps.dev.microsoft.com

This is just the microsoft v2 application registration / management console, where I have visited, where I have an application. Creating a new application does not help. None of the docs, whether specific to Microsoft Knowledge APIs, to Cognitive Services, or more broad ones, seem to help.

There's a few other questions whose titles are pretty much the same as this one, but I think they're all for 2016-2017. Things have changed a lot. You can't create a cognitive service in the Azure portal anymore, as it seems was possible before. There are some Cognitive Services APIs which look approachable here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/try/cognitive-services/my-apis/ (found via those old questions). But not the one I'm interested in, the Academic Knowledge APIs. I've looked around a lot. Are these APIs just not in use anymore, or what?

For reference, I tested out my keys using this suggested code snippet:

```
curl -v -X GET "https://api.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/academic/v1.0/interpret?query={string}&complete=0&count=10&offset={number}&timeout={number}&model=latest"
-H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: {subscription key}"

--data-ascii "{body}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve your Microsoft Cognitive Services Labs keys by going to https://labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions and signing in with your account, Hotmail, LinkedIn, or GitHub.

Looks like the auto generated API reference at the first URL you had included has an incorrect profile link.