# Bing image Search API fails

Tags: android, azure, rest

I try to download an image via bing image search api. I get an error after open the connection to the endpoint:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/images/search?q=Der+Rueckkehrer+Bluray

Here my code:

```
    String subscriptionKey = "my sub key";

    String host = "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com";
    String path = "/bing/v7.0/images/search";


    URL url = new URL(host + path + "?q=" +  URLEncoder.encode(productName, "UTF-8"));
    HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestProperty("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", subscriptionKey);

    System.out.println("URL " + url);
    // receive JSON body
    InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();  <--- Crash
    bingResult = readStream(stream);
```

Comment: Can you check the status code for the connection please? You can get `FileNotException` when response code is between 400 and 499

Comment: via getResponseMessage() it returns: PermissionDenied

Comment: `connection.getResponseCode();` will return the status code

Comment: it returns 401 , if you click the url displayed in the log it also returns this {"error":{"code":"401","message":"Access denied due to invalid subscription key or wrong API endpoint. Make sure to provide a valid key for an active subscription and use a correct regional API endpoint for your resource."}}

Comment: The subscription key I have directly from azure cognitive services.

Comment: Perhaps its not cognitive services sub key? I actually cant find there the bing search api but only the bing search custom api

Comment: Are you using the correct Subscription key? Did you get the key from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/cognitive-services-apis-create-account)?

Comment: this is a good question. I have added a cognitive services resource and got that key.

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49763351/how-do-i-get-a-subscription-key-for-microsoft-cognitive-services-apis) help?

Comment: I think the problem is that I cant find in azure the Bing Search API. I can find the cognitive services but there is only bing search and nothing with image.

Comment: It keeps telling 401 also if I use the search endpoint. There are 2 subkeys. Do I have to add anything Else like Account key?

Comment: No. That should do. Let me check the docs.

Comment: @MadhanVaradhodiyil did you find any hint? There are two sub keys, as far as I understand both should work.

Comment: I have no not used cognitive services key but directly bing api search and it works. But it is only a 7 day drial. I dont get how to buy it.

Comment: This is totaly strange, I cant find the bing api search in azure console, but via google search and it has different keys as the conginitive services

Comment: Fixed it. Have to add Bing search not cognitive Service

Comment: Ah! Sorry, I couldn't be of much help. Was held up at work